# Validate that subnet is within vnet in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-virtual-network

I am working on an ARM template for deploying resources in Azure, and
I would like to add some validation in the parameters the user can specify.

In my deployment, the user can specify that he wants to deploy the resources in a certain *virtual network* and in a certain *subnet*.

Right now, it is possible to specify a subnet which does not exist and the deployment of the resources will launch, only to fail afterwards.

**Is there any way to validate that the subnet is indeed within that virtual network, so that the validation occurs straightaway and the deployment does not start in the first place**?

---

In AWS, this can be achieved with the *Constraints* rule:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/latest/adminguide/reference-template_constraint_rules.html

Is there an equivalent for ARM templates?
I didn't find anything in the [docs for ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, there is nothing like that in the ARM Template syntax, you need to create a script and run it before invoking the template to check that. alternatively you can create a list of possible values and define all the subnets the person can deploy his stuff using the `allowedvalues` property of a parameter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#parameters

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I had missed something but doesn't look like it. Seems very limiting... What would a script look like? Is there some sort of preprocessor that can be defined in an ARM template? If so, could you provide an example in your answer? Thanks again.

Comment: no, you cant define preprocessor in the template, but you can have a script that tests these values and if they pass - deploys the template.

Comment: The templates are deployed directly in Azure though, from the portal. So looks like there is no solution?

Comment: from the portal - well, no easy solution, you can do some sort of hacking, but it wont be pretty, really its easier to make people use custom ways of deploying them